# HTML CSS Move block upwards as far as possible

Tags: html, css, block

I have six blocks with different heights and 33% width.

The third block (last in the first row) has a greater height than the first two.

The 4th and 5th blocks are aligned to the bottom of the 3th, but I need them to shift up.

I have:

```
---- ---- ----
|  | |  | |  | 
---- ---- |  |
          ----
---- ---- ----
|  | |  | |  |
---- ---- ----
```

I want:

```
---- ---- ----
|  | |  | |  | 
---- ---- |  |
---- ---- ----
|  | |  | ----
---- ---- |  |
          ----
```

In the html, the blocks are in divs and not grouped in rows or anything.

In Css I have put `float:left`, `height` and `width` on it and used `box-sizing:border-box`..

Hope it makes sense.. Any ideas?

Comment: Show the code please?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to use js, take a look at http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Or you'll have to divide them by column and not row, put the boxes in the different columns, and then float the columns

Comment: @JonasGrumann Was afraid so, thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: @JonasGrumann Thanks, but that's not an option for me, because it's put together by a system which isn't able to divide them in rows.